Book series about a soldier or ex-soldier that is brought back to life using magic
I've read the first book in a series sometime ago where some kind of soldier I believe dies but some government agency brings him back to life using some djinn?/magic powers.
All that I remember:

he escapes the facility he was in
he has to duct tape parts of his body together
he re-unites with his wife and child
they are on the run through some wilderness at one point.


Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be more specific about when you read this?  Do you recall the cover art at all, or the names of any characters or locations in the story?

Hi @davidw, thanks!. I've found it by going into an old old saved playlist of mine :D It's called Gemini Cell by Myke Cole, part of the Reawakening Trilogy, released in 2015.

Found it: Gemini Cell by Myke Cole, part of the "Reawakening Trilogy," released in 2015.
Quoting from the blurb on Goodreads:

US Navy SEAL Jim Schweitzer is a consummate professional, a fierce warrior, and a hard man to kill. But when he sees something he was never meant to see on a covert mission gone bad, he finds himself—and his family—in the crosshairs. Nothing means more to Jim than protecting his loved ones, but when the enemy brings the battle to his front door, he is overwhelmed and taken down.
It should be the end of the story. But Jim is raised from the dead by a sorcerer and recruited by a top secret unit dabbling in the occult, known only as the Gemini Cell. With powers he doesn’t understand, Jim is called back to duty—as the ultimate warrior. As he wrestles with a literal inner demon, Jim realizes his new superiors are determined to use him for their own ends and keep him in the dark—especially about the fates of his wife and son…


Cool! Don't forget to click the checkmark at the top left of your answer to mark it as accepted.
